# AutoLayout Not working on UILabel

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a view in Tab Bar Controller with a UIImageView and UILabel.  I have the UILabel positioned so the text will appear inside of a heart in the UIImageView.  The image view takes up the entire view.  I am using AutoLayout to position everything, and have it set to stretch the image to fill the entire screen when rotated, but I am running into issues getting the UILabel where I want it.

I have tried pinning Top To SuperView, but that causes the UILabel to be too low, and pinning to bottom pushes the UILabel out of view when rotated.  Here is the image showing first thing.

UPDATE:  I have tried the following code, to no avail:

```
-(void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        NSLog(@"Landscape left");
 label1.frame = CGRectMake(29, 20, 509, 142);
        [label1 setFrame:CGRectMake(29, 20, 509, 142)];

    } else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        NSLog(@"Landscape right");
         label1.frame = CGRectMake(29, 20, 509, 142);
        [label1 setFrame:CGRectMake(29, 20, 509, 142)];

    } else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
        NSLog(@"Portrait");
        [label1 setFrame:CGRectMake(29, 77, 61, 142)];
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never set frames directly when using auto layout. All moving and resizing should be done through constraints. You can set the position of your label in code using the multiplier and constant in such a way that the view will automatically change its position without having to check on the orientation. For instance, if you have this,

```
NSLayoutConstraint *con = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:subview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:0 toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:0.2 constant:-60];
```

subview would be positioned 53.6 points from the top in portrait and 4 points from the top in landscape. It's kind of a pain to do the calculations to figure out what numbers to plug in there, so I've written a category on NSLayoutConstraint to do that for me. So the category has one method that looks like this:

```
+(NSLayoutConstraint *)topConstraintForView:(UIView *)subview viewAttribute:(NSLayoutAttribute) att superview:(UIView *)superview portraitValue:(CGFloat)pValue landscapeValue:(CGFloat)lValue {
    CGFloat multiplier = (pValue - lValue)/(superview.bounds.size.height - superview.bounds.size.width);
    CGFloat constant = pValue - (superview.bounds.size.height * multiplier);
    NSLayoutConstraint *con = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:subview attribute:att relatedBy:0 toItem:superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:multiplier constant:constant];
    return con;
}
```

You use it very simply, like this:

```
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint topConstraintForView:self.label viewAttribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop superview:self.view portraitValue:100 landscapeValue:50]];
```

This will calculate the correct values for the multiplier and constant, and position the view correctly. In IB, you need to have a top constraint to your label, that you remove before adding this one. You can do that by editing the constraint, and checking the box that's titled, "Placeholder Remove at build time".

If you want to do this without using a category, you can change the method slightly, and add it to the class where you're setting the constraint. Like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view addConstraint:[self topConstraintForView:self.label viewAttribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop superview:self.view portraitValue:100 landscapeValue:50]];
}



-(NSLayoutConstraint *)topConstraintForView:(UIView *)subview viewAttribute:(NSLayoutAttribute) att superview:(UIView *)superview portraitValue:(CGFloat)pValue landscapeValue:(CGFloat)lValue {
    CGFloat multiplier = (pValue - lValue)/(superview.bounds.size.height - superview.bounds.size.width);
    CGFloat constant = pValue - (superview.bounds.size.height * multiplier);
    NSLayoutConstraint *con = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:subview attribute:att relatedBy:0 toItem:superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:multiplier constant:constant];
    return con;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but on the `self.view addConstraint` I get class method for topConstraintForView not found.

Comment: @user717452, you would have to add the category to do it the way I did. I've updated my answer to show you how to do it without adding a category.

Comment: Can the same kind of thing work for UIBarButtonItems that are added programatically?

Comment: @user717452, I don't know -- the way buttons are positioned on a tool bar or navigation bar might be different. Try it and see.

Comment: It crashed the app, but that could have also been due to the UIBarButtonItem created in code, and not in IB

Comment: I ended up just setting an array of button items to the rightBarButtonItem, and letting the navigation controller arrange everything for me.

Answer (score 0):

Having been here endless times I would suggest using code to position the label as required in your rotation methods. Create an IBOutlet and then adjust the frame to one of two positions when the device rotates.

Comment: Tried this using willRotateToInterfaceOrientation, and setting the frame for the UILabel for each orientation, but it made no change at all.  I added NSLogs for each orientation, and those fire properly when rotated, but the frame doesn't work.

Comment: Have you connected up the IBOutlet ?

Comment: Yes.  Verified just now that it was.

Answer (score 0):

More then likely you are going to have to make the text a smaller size in order to fit inside the heart dynamically. Also if the heart is not a view of its own, make it its own. That would help auto layout to know how to define itself better. Also to help maybe get more of an understanding this is a great resource http://nsscreencast.com/episodes/35-autolayout-fun

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Simple step, 
Just use **constraints**, relevant to your need.

[image]

and then, set the **Relation >= or <= or ==** based on your need.
Also set number of lines in interface builder.

[image]

Ref: https://medium.com/@elgoni/ios-7-auto-layout-3e50cd1d1278